# iPhone 5 simulator does a segue to an old login view controller on Facebook login

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

My initial view controller is my login screen which has username, password, and login with Facebook. If you click the login with Facebook button it takes you to Facebook, then brings you back to the initial view controller and segue's to a tab view controller.

When I run the simulator for iPhone 4s it runs fine, iPhone 5s it runs fine, iPhone 6 it runs fine, but if I run it on iPhone 5 it will go from the Facebook login in Safari then goes back to an older version of my initial view controller that isn't even on my main storyboard anymore.

Does anyone know why this might be happening and how to fix it? I don't get how it is segueing back to a view controller layout that isn't even there anymore. Any help would be great.

Here is my Facebook login code:

```
@IBAction func facebookLogin(sender: AnyObject) {

    loginType = 1

    let permissions = ["public_profile","email"]

    PFFacebookUtils.logInInBackgroundWithReadPermissions(permissions, block: {

        (user: PFUser?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

        if let error = error {

            println(error)

        } else {

            if let user = user {

                if let alreadyRegistered: String = user["name"] as? String {

                    println("Already Registered")
                    println(user)
                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fbLogin", sender: self)

                } else {

                    println("New Register")
                    println(user)
                    newUserMessage = 1

                    let graphRequest = FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields": "id, name, email"])
                    graphRequest.startWithCompletionHandler( {

                        (connection, result, error) -> Void in //we are not returning anything

                        if error != nil {

                            print(error)

                        } else if let result: AnyObject = result {

                            print(result)
                            PFUser.currentUser()?["name"] = result["name"]
                            PFUser.currentUser()?["email"] = result["email"]
                            PFUser.currentUser()?.saveInBackgroundWithBlock({ (Bool, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                                if error != nil {

                                    println(error)

                                }

                            })

                        }

                        })

                    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("fbLogin", sender: self)

                }

            }

        }

    })

}
```

Comment: Try one of these.
1. Clean Project
2. Remove derived data folder
3. Uninstall app from simulator and install again.

Comment: I have done 1 and 3. How do I remove the derived data folder?

Comment: From Xcode Menu `Window > Projects` and from the window, left pane, select your project then from the right pane, you should see a Derived Data label, with a delete button on right. Delete it.

Comment: I deleted all the apps from the iPhone 5 simulator and then deleted the derived data and now it works. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too, and nothing was getting fixed. Your best bet is to try and remove your old app from the iPhone 5 simulator, then deep clean your current build, and run it. (I ended up deleting my old app completely and that worked out, too.)